# Unsupported method ('POST'): 501 - Server does not support this operation

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple login page but I keep on getting an error:

> Message: Unsupported method ('POST'). Error code explanation: 501 -
> Server does not support this operation.

This is the code I'm using.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Core123"

# Enter your database connection details below
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "Core@123!"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "pythonlogin"

# Initialize MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/pythonlogin/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        return "You are already logged in!"

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        # Retrieve the hashed password
        hash = hashlib.sha1((password + app.secret_key).encode()).hexdigest()

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password 
          = %s",
            (username, hash),
        )
        account = cursor.fetchone()

        if account:
            session["loggedin"] = True
            session["id"] = account[0]
            session["username"] = account[1]
            return "Logged in successfully!"
        else:
            return "Incorrect username/password!"

    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        return "You are logged in!"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


   if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code, paste your code into a code block in your post instead.

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin I will repost after 90 minutes since the is no block code button on the comment section

Comment: Please do not repost.  You need to [edit] your question.  There is a an "Edit" link right under the tags or you can use the edit link I put in this comment.

Comment: You don't have a route named "login", you have a route named "pythonlogin". You must either change the name of the route or change the string that you pass to `url_for`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb-onstrike Thank you for your respond I have changed the code to what you have asked me to change it too but I'm not really sure on how to use the "url_for" statement may you please send me a short code on how I should use it.<code>@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        return "You are already logged in!"

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]</code>

Comment: Your question still says `@app.route("/pythonlogin/", ...` Edit your question, do not change your question in comments.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thank you for your respond.I'm still new on Stackoverflow I'm not really sure what you are requesting of me. but I have tried other project that uses a POST statement and they all giving the same error. I don't think it the coding I think I need to configure something on MYSQL workbench, Visual Studio Code or Python